# Elasticsearch: Is it possible to update by query with a size limit?

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to do an update by query `(_update_by_query`), and I only want 100 documents to be affected. An analogy in SQL is `UPDATE foo SET a = 5 LIMIT 100`. Is it possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since 7.3, the `_update_by_query` API supports the `max_docs` parameter, which you can use to specify the maximum number of documents to update

```
POST foo/_update_by_query?max_docs=100
{
  "script": {
    "source": "ctx._source.a = 5"
  }
}
```